# Is it possible to control a matrix of motors using H-bridges?

Tags: motor, h-bridge

I am wondering if it is possible to control a matrix of motors using H-bridges? A design in my mind is shown in the picture. I haven't seen anyone doing something similar, so I am wondering if there is any technical difficulty here?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Probably just lack of applications that have a lot of brushed motors where only one needs to be run at at time. The EMI might be pretty bad though. I think it's possible for some motors to cause other motors to spin when they are slowing down but I haven't traced the current paths. Hmmm. I actually have stack of circuit boards capable of doing this just laying around at work.

Answer (score 2):

I love this question!

EDIT: finally sat down to think about this and it is not feasible as presented. Without diodes (like an LED matrix) current can flow through unselected motors (or really any bidirectional load) and cause all sorts of havoc, here's a diagram to illustrate:

[image: unintended current flow]

****** original answer follows ******

My answer is yes, but with one caveat that I can see: if you’re switching between motors fast enough you can be in a situation where one inactive motor is spinning and it’s back EMF will be added to the voltage of one of the driven lines and either forward bias the body diodes of your driver FETs or overwhelm the Vce/Vec limits of your transistors.

[image]

Here's that diagram I promised, say you set row1 positive and column 1 negative for a time - M1 spins up to speed and has a non trivial BEMF, call it 10 volts. Now that M1 is spinning your controller decides to spin M2 in reverse - Row 1 is deactivated, row 2 is brought to negative and column 1 is now positive. The voltage at the row1 node is now column 1 plus the BEMF of M1, which in this case is 10V. If the driver transistors are regular MOSFETs then the body diode will become forward biased in the high side driver of row 1 and significant current will flow until M1 has dumped some of its energy, column 1 becomes low voltage, or one of the drive transistors lets the smoke out. If the drive transistors are BJTs there isn't a body diode to worry about anymore, but there's a significant reverse bias on the collector-emitter pair, and probably also the base-emitter pair - the BJT's can be sized to accommodate this... I think. Note that if all the motors are driven the same direction then you're adding the BEMF of an arbitrary motor to ground, which is less likely to exceed your supply voltage and all the worries about body diodes and overvoltage disappear, as was already mentioned by our esteemed colleague @Gil

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does it mean that the back EMF will activate the other motors that are not addressed? I initially thought the motors that are not addressed will not be affected by the back EMF because the MOSEFET in the half h-bridge is fully off and doesn't allow current to go through. Please correct me if this is not the case.

Comment: @a12345 there's that diagram - certainly not my best work but I hope I got my meaning across. Indeed you are correct that the BEMF of one motor will not affect the other undriven motors (...i think, let me sleep on it) however the BEMF can get back into the supply in upsetting ways, as detailed above.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! This is very useful!

Comment: @a12345 last edit, I promise: this isn't feasible as drawn because the loads wont be isolated from eachother. I've attached a diagram to the top of my answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. A patent was filed 1/2001 US6583591B2 owned by Yazaki doing almost the same thing. It has a good explanation that may help you. It uses a single 1/2 bridge for one side and several 1/2 bridges for the other side, one per motor. This allowed multiple motors to operate concurrently as long as the direction was consistent. The motors could be wired appropriately to realize this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am also wondering if I can address each single motor in the matrix by multiplexer or shift register?

Comment: That can be done without any major problems however you must design the hardware to support your solution. The motors I used were for automotive and similar drawing in the 10A to 40A range.